# How to avoid empty Undo groups in NSUndoManager?

Tags: nsundomanager

I have been getting empty undo/redo groups in my undoManager undo/redo stacks..Hence getting canUndo/canRedo as TRUE in many cases..
How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

One way that I've avoided this is to detect when an empty event is created and then just silently undo it. In a subclass of `NSUndoManager`:

```
@interface MyUndoManager : NSUndoManager
@property BOOL haveReceivedInvocationPreparation;
@end

@implementation MyUndoManager

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.haveReceivedInvocationPreparation = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)endUndoGrouping {
    [super endUndoGrouping];

    if (self.groupingLevel == 0) {
        if (!self.haveReceivedInvocationPreparation && !self.isUndoing) {
            [self disableUndoRegistration];
            [self undo];
            [self enableUndoRegistration];
        }
        self.haveReceivedInvocationPreparation = NO;
    }
}

- (id)prepareWithInvocationTarget:(id)target {
    self.haveReceivedInvocationPreparation = YES;
    return [super prepareWithInvocationTarget:target];
}

@end
```

This seems to work well so far and I have yet to see any weird behaviour because of it.

Comment: How do you register your undos? As I'm not getting calls to `prepareWithInvocationTarget` when simply this one is called: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/undomanager/2427208-registerundo

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot avoid that the NSUndoManager counts empty undo groups as valid undo actions.
One solution is to use the GCUndoManager, which tries to fix the problem of empty groups, see http://apptree.net/gcundomanager.htm